# Delete row if row contains 000

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following code:

```
set local enabledelayedexpansion for /f "delims=" %%a in  (\\file) do ( 
  SET ='%%a 
  SET s=!s:;'';'=;;%!
  echo !s!
)  >>   \\file"
```

I need apart from the modification, to delete the row if contains 00.
So far i have tried to add the following set but is not working.

Comment: It would be appreciated were you to explain exactly your search string(s) because from the comment you made regarding my answer it is obvious that you are not intending to remove all lines containing `000`.

Answer (score 1):

Does

```bat
FIND /V "000"<"TXTFILE.TXT">"NEWFILE.TXT"
```

or

```bat
TYPE "TXTFILE.TXT"|FIND /V "000">"NEWFILE.TXT"
```

not do what you want?

Comment: it´s deleting everything, even rows that it shouldn´t delete

Comment: As `FIND` is a longstanding command which is known to work in normal circumstances, and is written correctly above I'd suspect the string you are looking not to match is not that which is entered in your question title. _(the regex and SET lines you've given do not make it clear)_.