# Batch file: row in txt file contains xxx then do one thing, else do nothing

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make the modify a text file.

Right now i have some modifications that are applying always.

I want to make before the changes the conditional that if a row contains xxxx then do nothing else do the changes. Here i paste you the code.

```html
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET "TMPFILE=%TEMP%\file_converter_%RANDOM%.tmp"
IF EXIST "%TMPFILE%" (DEL "%TMPFILE%")

for /f "delims=" %%a in (economic_changes.txt) do (
   SET "s='%%a "
   SET "s=!s:;= ! "
   SET "s=!s:- =-;;! "
   SET "s=!s: -=-! "
   SET "s=!s:-;;-=-;-! "
   SET "s=!s:-=%!"
   SET "s=!s:_= %!"
   SET "s=!s:;=';'%!"
   SET "s=!s:;'';'=;;%!"

   echo>>"%TMPFILE% !s!
)

COPY /Y "%TMPFILE%" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Economic_Folder\economic_changes.txt"
IF EXIST "%TMPFILE%" (DEL "%TMPFILE%")
```

Comment: [It would help if you responded to me in your last but one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438145/delete-row-if-row-contains-000), which is essentially the same. You need to exactly show us the match string.

Comment: i have the data this way:-state;of;prot-;-201705-;-ID1-;-SOLD-;-4-;-PROD;2-;; and i would like if string contains state to make changes, if not do nothing. thank yo

Answer (score 0):

Insert an echo to find with conditional execution on fail `||`

```
@Echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET "TMPFILE=%TEMP%\file_converter_%RANDOM%.tmp"
IF EXIST "%TMPFILE%" (DEL "%TMPFILE%")

for /f "delims=" %%a in (economic_changes.txt) do (
    Echo:%%a|find "xxx" >NUL 2>&1||(
        SET "s='%%a "
        SET "s=!s:;= ! "
        SET "s=!s:- =-;;! "
        SET "s=!s: -=-! "
        SET "s=!s:-;;-=-;-! "
        SET "s=!s:-=%!"
        SET "s=!s:_= %!"
        SET "s=!s:;=';'%!"
        SET "s=!s:;'';'=;;%!"
    )
    echo>>"%TMPFILE% !s!
)

COPY /Y "%TMPFILE%" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Economic_Folder\economic_changes.txt"
IF EXIST "%TMPFILE%" (DEL "%TMPFILE%")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated in your comment that you are wanting to make the changes if a line contains a string match, then you'd need to use **`&&`** instead of **`||`**. You have now provided an indication, *(poor though it may be)*, of your file content which has lead me to a best guess for your string match, *(it isn't `000` or `xxx`)*.

```bat
For /F UseBackDelims^=^ EOL^= %%a In ("economic_changes.txt") Do (
    Echo=%%a|Findstr/IRC:"[-\;]state[-\;]">Nul 2>&1&&(
        Set …
```

If you are looking for only lines with that string, i.e. delete all lines not containing it, *(as opposed to ignoring them)*, then just use this to extract them.

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Findstr/IRC:"[-\;]state[-\;]" "economic_changes.txt"'
) Do Set …
```

Or you could extract them all to a new file first, as I advised in the question you had previously asked then ignored.

```bat
Findstr/IRC:"[-\;]state[-\;]" "economic_changes.txt">"NewFile.txt"
```

***In all cases above if the string is supposed to be the first in a line as shown in your comment then you could further improve accuracy by using `Findstr/BIRC:"[-\;]state[-\;]"`.***